# Trouble With NSDateFormatter TimeZone Format

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdateformatter

I have a time stamp that looks like this...

```
2015-02-04T01:02:27.363Z
```

Im using this but it doesn't work...

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.ZZZZ"];
```

Ive tried a few different things but I don't quite understand the formatting of timezones.
Can someone point out what the proper format is for a date like this?
Thanks

Comment: use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzzZ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as below.

> ```
> NSString *dateStr = @"2015-02-04T01:02:27.363Z";
> NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
> [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzzZ"];
> NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
> ```